# Getting the download link for a public Google Docs file

Tags: python, api, google-docs

Reading the [Google Docs API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#DownloadingFiles) I find this:

> ### Downloading
>
> Files cannot be downloaded in a format other than
>   the one in which they were originally uploaded. The download URL for
>   files looks something like this:
>
> ```
> https://doc-04-20-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/secure/m7an0emtau/WJm12345/YzI2Y2ExYWVm?h=16655626&e=download&gd=true
> ```

Given a public Google Documents file URL, say,

```
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1-vl-dPgKm_NTNhZjZkMWMtZjQxOS00MGE1LTg2MjItNGVjYzdmZjYxNmQ5
```

How can I turn it into a download link?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hi nightcracker try this:

```
https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=DOCIDGOESHERE
```

I've only tried it with one pdf and it worked ok so maybe having a play with that will help....

All the best,

Dave

Comment: You are amazing indeed! I have been looking for this for HOURS! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The method suggested by dkcwd didn't work for a published document.

I have found the following method in [this page](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com.tr/2007/07/download-published-documents-and.html). Given a publish document URL, such as

```
https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=[ID]
```

The download link is

```
https://docs.google.com/document/export?format=[FORMAT]&id=[ID]
```

where `[FORMAT]` can be one of these values: `pdf, doc, docx, oo, rtf, txt`.